# Read and write to file using bash

Tags: linux, shell-script, curl, read-write

Problem statement:

1. Read a file line by line
2. Execute a command on each file
3. Print the line and output of command in another file

**Input file (urls.txt):**

```
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.bing.com
```

**Expected output file (output.csv):**

```
www.google.com,200
www.yahoo.com,500
www.bing.com,404
```

**Script I have so far**

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    curl -LI "$line" -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s
 >> output.csv
done < urls.txt
```

*not an expert in bash scripting. just a beginner. any help is much appreciated. Thank you. :)*

Comment: So what is your question, exactly?

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: I want the output mentioned in Expected output file. Currently output.csv would only contain the http codes i.e. only the output of the command. Output I want is for 'www.google.com','200' is the response

Comment: So please [edit] your question to tell us that. You've shown us what you've tried - that's great. But what does it do that you don't want it to do, and what doesn't it do that you do want it to do?

Answer (score 1):

By using echo and command substitution formatting of each line can be done like that:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "$line,$(curl -LI "$line" -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}\n' -s)" >> output.csv
done < urls.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `%{url_effective}` in the `-w` output fields:

```
awk -v OFS== -v out=/dev/null \
    '!/^(#|[[:blank:]]*$)/{print "url", $0; print "out", out}' urls.txt |

curl -K- -sSLI -w '%{num_redirects},%{url_effective},%{http_code}\n' >> output.csv
```

- Because `-L` is used to follow redirects, there may be some discrepencies between the urls from `urls.txt` and `%{url_effective}`. If the first url gives a 3xx response, the first column from the output above will be greater than zero, the second column will contain last url followed (not the initial url from `urls.txt`)
- Above, instead of looping over the file and calling `curl` on each line, `awk` is used to turn `urls.txt` into a "config" file for curl which is then piped to `curl`. The formatting for this is specific to curl – for more info, search for `-K` in `man 1 curl`

e.g.

```
$ cat urls.txt
https://unix.stackexchange.com/
#www.example.com
https://unix.stackexchange.com/question
http://unix.stackexchange.com/

$ awk -v OFS== '!/^(#|[[:blank:]]*$)/{print "url",$0; print "out","/dev/null"}' \
urls.txt | curl -K- -sSLI -w '%{num_redirects},%{url_effective},%{http_code}\n'
0,https://unix.stackexchange.com/,200
0,https://unix.stackexchange.com/question,404
1,https://unix.stackexchange.com/,200
```